# Replace text in column, if column header is a specific text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report which plots venue availability against dates (see layout below)

[image]

The information comes through as Fullday / Morning / Afternoon, and if used will say Booked.

None of the venues are used on Sundays, except to set up. However, this data still comes through as a full day availability, which messes with calculations used for reporting later down the line (can look like the venues have offered more availability than they actually have).

I have the following two pieces of code in place already:

```
Sub Find_replace()
Range("A:AAA").Select
Selection.Replace What:="Fullday", Replacement:="***Full", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
End Sub
```

This searches for cells with “Fullday” and replaces it with “***Full” across the entire worksheet.

```
Sub Sunday_widths()
Dim Range1 As Range
Dim Cell1 As Range
Set Range1 = Range("O1:AAA1")
    For Each Cell1 In Range1
        Select Case True
            Case Celll Like "*Sun*"
                Cell1.ColumnWidth = 7.5
        End Select
    Next Cell1
End Sub
```

This searches for any column with “Sun” in Row 1, and sets the width of the column based on that.

Is there any way to combine these two, so that the macro searches for any column with Sun in the top row, selects that column and replaces any text “***Full” with “Set up”?

Thanks very much in advance!

EDIT:

```
Sub Sunday_avails()

Dim Range1 As Range
Dim Cell1 As Range
Set Range1 = Range("O1:AAA1")
    For Each Cell1 In Range1
        Select Case True
            Case Celll Like "*Sun*"
                Cell1.EntireColumn.Replace What:="***Full", Replacement:="*Set up", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
        End Select
    Next Cell1
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cell1.EntireColumn.Replace What:=....`

Comment: You also do not need to `.Select` anything to make replacements.

Comment: Hi @BigBig, I've edited in your suggestion, but when I run it it's not doing anything (not coming up with an error either) - do you know why?

Comment: You need `Option Explicit` at the top of the module; it would catch the typo. `Case Cell1`, not `Case Celll`.

Comment: **Note 1** | Make sure to use explicit range references. It's easy to forget but currently you may refer to the implicit `ActiveSheet` without wanting to do so.

Comment: **Note 2** | Since sunday is always the 7th day, I think you may be able to refrain from looping over all these columns and `Case` alltogether. Specify your starting column and end, then `Step` over this range =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simplified alternative to stepping over all columns:

```
Dim cl1 As Long, cl2 As Long, x As Long

With Sheet1 'Specify your sheet's codename
    cl1 = .Range("1:1").Find("Sun").Column
    cl2 = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For x = cl1 To cl2 Step 7
        .Columns(x).Replace What:="***Full", Replacement:="*Set up"
    Next
End With
```

This would be usefull if you can confirm a step of 7 is appropriate on your data layout. In any case, even if the above isn't applicable, it's usefull to know the last used column to prevent a lot of unneccesary calls to the sheet object =)

Comment: Hi - it would be a step of 9 (two columns repeat every week with additional info), so I amended it. It works brilliantly - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just call `Replace` on the `.EntireColumn`:

```
Cell1.EntireColumn.Replace What:="***Full", Replacement:="*Set up"...
```

Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module, and it would catch the typo in your latest edit:

```
Case Celll Like "*Sun*"
```

should be

```
Case Cell1 Like "*Sun*"
```